# NullPointerException while reading XML file using StreamSource

Tags: jaxb

I want to parse an XML from middle( Leaving the root node and processing from second node onwards). The code which i have written is

```
    JAXBContent jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{Src.Fapmgr_Diag_Summary.class});
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    StreamSource xml_reader = new StreamSource("C:/Users/Ner/Desktop/Analysis/FAPMgrDiagnosticsSummary_apply_20140723112656.xml");
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml_reader);
    System.out.println(xsr.nextTag);
```

But I am getting **NullpointerException**. The variable - "xml_reader" is containing **NULL** as may be it is not able to read the XML. What is wrong with it? Any wrong way of mentioning the location of file?

The error-stacktrace is

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.nextTag(StreamReaderDelegate.java:66)
at oracle.ERP.Cloud.model.Module.AppModuleAMImpl.ParseXML(AppModuleAMImpl.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.invokeMethod(DCInvokeMethod.java:638)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.invokeMethod(DCDataControl.java:2136)
at oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.invokeMethod(DCJboDataControl.java:3063)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCInvokeMethod.callMethod(DCInvokeMethod.java:261)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.doIt(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:1635)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCDataControl.invokeOperation(DCDataControl.java:2143)
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlActionBinding.invoke(JUCtrlActionBinding.java:740)
at oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PageLifecycleImpl.executeEvent(PageLifecycleImpl.java:394)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding._execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:252)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlActionBinding.execute(FacesCtrlActionBinding.java:210)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at oracle.adf.controller.internal.util.ELInterfaceImpl.invokeMethod(ELInterfaceImpl.java:168)
at oracle.adfinternal.controller.activity.MethodCallActivityLogic.execute(MethodCallActivityLogic.java:160)
at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.executeActivity(ControlFlowEngine.java:989)
at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.doRouting(ControlFlowEngine.java:878)
at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.doRouting(ControlFlowEngine.java:777)
at oracle.adfinternal.controller.engine.ControlFlowEngine.invokeTaskFlow(ControlFlowEngine.java:242)
at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ChildViewPortContextImpl.invokeTaskFlow(ChildViewPortContextImpl.java:104)
at oracle.adfinternal.controller.state.ControllerState.createChildViewPort(ControllerState.java:1351)
at oracle.adfinternal.controller.ControllerContextImpl.createChildViewPort(ControllerContextImpl.java:78)
at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.createRegionViewPortContext(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:429)
at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.DCTaskFlowBinding.getViewPort(DCTaskFlowBinding.java:352)
at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.doProcessBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:160)
at oracle.adf.controller.internal.binding.TaskFlowRegionModel.processBeginRegion(TaskFlowRegionModel.java:108)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion$RegionContextChange.doChangeImpl(UIXRegion.java:1199)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.context.DoableContextChange.doChange(DoableContextChange.java:91)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion._beginInterruptibleRegion(UIXRegion.java:693)
at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.processRegion(UIXRegion.java:498)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.RegionTag.doStartTag(RegionTag.java:127)
at jsp_servlet.__mainflow_jspx._jspx___tag3(__mainflow_jspx.java:243)
at jsp_servlet.__mainflow_jspx._jspx___tag2(__mainflow_jspx.java:204)
at jsp_servlet.__mainflow_jspx._jspx___tag1(__mainflow_jspx.java:154)
at jsp_servlet.__mainflow_jspx._jspx___tag0(__mainflow_jspx.java:104)
at jsp_servlet.__mainflow_jspx._jspService(__mainflow_jspx.java:65)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:326)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:523)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:410)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.RecordRequestAttributesDuringDispatch.dispatch(RecordRequestAttributesDuringDispatch.java:44)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:469)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:140)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:777)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:293)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:213)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

Please help me out in it.

Comment: Try reading the file in using the Java `File` API first to make sure your path is right.

Comment: The variable `xml_reader` will *not* be `null`. Either it won't be in scope at all (if the constructor throws an exception) or it will be a non-null reference. The `new` operator *never* returns `null`. Now what *exactly* are you seeing? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: Additionally, the code you've posted wouldn't compile, as `nextTag` is a method, not a field. That makes me wonder what else about your real code isn't the same as what you've posted.

Comment: I was able to see the variable xml_reader as Null when i debugged it. Initially when i tried to parse the same xml using createXMLStreamReader (XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Ner\\Desktop\\Analysis\\FAPMgrDiagnosticsSummary_apply_20140723112656.xml")); ), it was successfull. Now since the xml content has changed and as i dont need to parse the entire xml, I am using StreamSource which is failing.